# Check if embed exists - aggregation framework mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is my test collection:

```
>db.test.find()
{
    "_id": ObjectId("54906479e89cdf95f5fb2351"),
    "reports": [
        {
            "desc": "xxx",
            "order": {"$id": ObjectId("53fbede62827b89e4f86c12e")}
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("54906515e89cdf95f5fb2352"),
    "reports": [
        {
            "desc": "xxx"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("549067d3e89cdf95f5fb2353"),
    "reports": [
        {
            "desc": "xxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to count all documents and documents with order, so:

```
>db.test.aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        all: {
            $sum: 1
        },
        order: {
            $sum: {
                "$cond": [
                    {
                        "$ifNull": ["$reports.order", false]
                    },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

and my results:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "all" : 3,
            "order" : 3
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

but expected:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "all" : 3,
            "order" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

It makes no difference what I'll put - "$reports.order", "$reports.xxx", etc, aggregation framework check only if the field reports exists, ignores embed.
$ifNull and $eq dosn't work with embeded documents?
Is any way to do something like this

```
db.test.find({"reports.order": {$exists: 1}})
```

in aggregation framework?
Sorry for my english and I hope that you understood what I want to show you :)

Comment: Why not just do `db.test.count()` to count the total number of documents and `db.test.count({ "reports.order" : { "$exists" : true } })` to count the number of documents with an order?

Comment: because I want do this in one query, it's a part of some statistic query builder, that was just sample code to show the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it doesn't work because the field "reports" contain an array, not an object.

I mean, your aggregation works as you expect in this collection:

```
>db.test.find() 
{
    "_id": ObjectId("54906479e89cdf95f5fb2351"),
    "reports":
        {
            "desc": "xxx",
            "order": {"$id": ObjectId("53fbede62827b89e4f86c12e")}
        }
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("54906515e89cdf95f5fb2352"),
    "reports": 
        {
            "desc": "xxx"
        }

},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("549067d3e89cdf95f5fb2353"),
    "reports": 
        {
            "desc": "xxx"
        }

}
```

**Note that I removed** the "[" and "]", so now it's an object, not an array (one-to-one relation).

Because you have array inside the "report" field, you need to unwind the array to output one document for each element. I suppose that if you have two "order" fields inside the "reports" array, you only wants to count it once. I mean:

```
 "reports": [
        {
            "desc": "xxx",
            "order": {"$id": ObjectId("53fbede62827b89e4f86c12e")},
            "order": "yyy",
        }
    ]
```

Should only count as one for the object final "order" sum.

In this case, you need to unwind, group by _id (because the previous example outputs two documents for the same _id) and then group again to count all documents:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$reports'}, 
    {$group:{
        _id:"$_id",
        order:{$sum:{"$cond": [
                {
                    "$ifNull": ["$reports.order", false]
                },
                1,
                0
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    {$group:{
        _id:null,
        all:{$sum:1},
        order: {
            $sum:{
                "$cond": [{$eq: ['$order', 0]}, 0, 1]
            }
        }
}}])
```

Maybe there is a shorter solution, but this works.